# PHP Doctrine ORM NestedSet

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, nested-sets

although I read through the manual here:
http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/hu/hierarchical-data
I couldn't find a way to move a node from a Leaf to become a Root node. Any clues?
The question is trivial for inserting a new node...but what about updating a node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Doctrine_Node_NestedSet::makeRoot()](http://www.doctrine-project.org/Doctrine_Node_NestedSet/1_2#method_makeroot) like so:

```
$item->getNode()->makeRoot($maxRootValue + 1);
```

You need to pass new `root_id` value and one of the easiest way to do this is to select `MAX(root_id)` from table and increment its value.

Answer (score 0):

As said Crozin, use `Doctrine_Node_NestedSet::makeRoot()`, but using the item's id instead of calculating the maximum value of the `root_id`.

The root_id is the id of the root node

```
$item->getNode()->makeRoot($item->id);
```

Is not necessary to calculate the value of `root_id`. Usign the item's id doesn't create any conflicts and is the way that Doctrine handled this internally.